# 'DataFrameGroupBy' object is not callable

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to extract these columns from this data sheet in Google Collab using pandas, but I keep getting the error "'DataFraneGroupBy' object is not callable" and I can't figure out why.

Here's the data sheet I'm working with:
https://files.catbox.moe/m6x7w0.xlsx

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: `JustOfficeSuppliesOrderID` is a DataFrameGroupBy object, and you are attempting to "call" it by doing `JustOfficeSuppliesOrderID(10)`. What is your expected output from this line of code? Please [edit] to include a [mcve] with a sample of your input data, your code as _text_ in the body of the question, and your expected output, so that we can better understand your task and question

Comment: groupby returns an object. you need to perform an aggregation or iterate over it, and not like you accessed it.  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues:

1. in your group by you need to include an aggregate function at the end (.count() or .sum() or etc.)
2. the result of JustOfficeSuppliesOrderID is a data frame, you need to call a function to data frames. I think you want to see the head or tail so try JustOfficeSuppliesOrderID.head(10).